# NetworkX - Keep order in edges

Tags: python, networkx

I have a bipartite graph B as follows:

```
B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from([5, 6, 7, 8], bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from([(1, 8), (1, 7), (1, 6), (1,5), (2,8), (2,7), (2,6), (3,8), (3,7), (4,8)])
```

I would like the order of the edges to remain as they are when I use `B.edges()`. Instead, they come out shuffled:

```
[(1, 8), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

The order may not necessarily be ascending or descending. I would just like it to be in the order I add them using `B.add_edges_from(...)`. So using `sorted` would not work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are the underlying data structure used for NetworkX graphs, and as of Python 3.7+ they maintain insertion order. This means that we will obtain the same result each time we run `Graph.edges()`.

For older pythons, you have Networkx's [`Ordered Graphs`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/ordered.html), which will give a consistent order for reporting of nodes and edges

```
g = nx.OrderedGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)
g.add_nodes_from([5, 6, 7, 8], bipartite=1)
g.add_edges_from([(1, 8), (1, 7), (1, 6), (1,5), 
                  (2,8), (2,7), (2,6), (3,8), (3,7), (4,8)])

print(g.edges())
# EdgeView([(1, 8), (1, 7), (1, 6), (1, 5), (2, 8), (2, 7), (2, 6), (3, 8), (3, 7)...
```

Comment: This not correct. Edges are not returned in injection order for OrderedGraphs. From the docs `The Ordered (Di/Multi/MultiDi) Graphs give a consistent order for reporting of nodes and edges. The order of node reporting agrees with node adding, but for edges, the order is not necessarily the order that the edges were added.`